# In song lyrics, how do you convey that a line or parts of a line is spoken at the same time?

Tags: creative-writing, lyrics

In song lyrics, how do you convey that a line or parts of a line is spoken at the same time?

Example:

> You are a fool, yeah that's right.

"You are a fool" is spoken by a different person. "Yeah that's right" is also spoken by a different person. The "Yeah" starts before "fool", how do you convey that?

Comment: If you have software with a big enough symbol library, there may be musical notes in it. The sung part will be begun and ended with a musical note, but still in quotes. This at least covers the singing part, but not the simultaneous part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sometimes film scripts have a similar problem](https://screenwriting.io/in-dialogue-how-do-you-express-that-one-character-is-interrupting-another/), where two lines spoken by different characters are meant to overlap or be spoken in an overlapping fashion. Or perhaps one character is meant to interrupt another character. In these cases, they typically write the lines like this:

> **CHARACTER 1**
> You are a fool --
>
> **CHARACTER 2**
> Yeah, that's right.

Or, alternatively, you can spell it out:

> **CHARACTER 1**
> You are a fool --
>
> **CHARACTER 2**
> (interrupting)
> Yeah, that's right.

The double ellipses in the first scenario are meant to indicate that the first character's dialogue is being interrupted, or talked over. In the second scenario, it is simply clarified with a marker.

In the specific case of **song lyrics,** however, you may want a different approach, since film scripts and lyrics might not necessarily be the same ballparks. An example I found of a song that has overlapping lyrics is [*I Hate This Part* by the Pussycat Dolls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S97MaG3kOMY) *(the overlaps happen at 0:23 and 1:30)*. Its lyrics are written on Google and other places as normal, despite parts of the song having overlapping words. So that seems to suggest you could just write the lyrics out as normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly uncommon, because of the difficulty in understanding overlapping lyrics, but it does happen, and there are a couple of different conventions.

Parentheses are often used for call-and-response, typically, but not always, with a soloist and chorus.

> Who's my baby? (I'm your baby!)

With a little imagination, this can be applied to imply an overlap:

> You are a (yeah) fool (that's right)

If it's only a few words that differ you sometimes see brackets and/or slashes.

> [You're/I'm] a fool

Extended sections with different lyrics are usually presented side by side.

```
SOLOIST                 CHOIR
You're a fool           Yeah, that's right, I know I'm a fool

BOTH
Such a stupid, stupid fool
```